# How do i fix keyerror in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, analysis

I have the following code:

```
for i in catvarList:    
    cat_num_0 = df_cat_0[i].value_counts(normalize=True)
    f,(ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3,sharey=True,gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[1,1, 0.001]},figsize=(15,4))
    print("Graph for : ",i)
    chart1=sns.barplot(x=cat_num_0.index, y=cat_num_0, ax=ax1,palette="Blues_d")
    chart1.set_xticklabels(chart1.get_xticklabels(), horizontalalignment='right')
    chart1.axes.set_title('Target 0',fontsize= 12,fontweight= 7,color='Green')
    cat_num_1=df_cat_1[i].value_counts(normalize=True)
    chart2=sns.barplot(x=cat_num_1.index, y=cat_num_1,ax=ax2,palette="Blues_d")
    chart2.set_xticklabels(chart2.get_xticklabels(), horizontalalignment='right')
    chart2.axes.set_title('Target 1',fontsize= 12,fontweight= 7,color='Green')
    plt.show()
```

But I am constantly getting this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'OWN_CAR_flag'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [72], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for i in catvarList:
----> 2     cat_num_0 = df_cat_0[i].value_counts(normalize=True)
      3     f,(ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3,sharey=True,gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[1,1, 0.001]},figsize=(15,4))
      4     print("Graph for : ",i)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
-> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624 except TypeError:
   3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'OWN_CAR_flag'
```

I have been using [this project](https://github.com/npbirari/Credit-EDA-Case-Study/blob/main/Credit%20EDA%20Case%20Study%20for%20Submission.ipynb) as a reference. It is the same but i am stuck on line 58 of the code provided here, and I could not find a solution by searching.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix the error?

Comment: Whats `df_cat_0`? A pandas dataframe? If so, what are its columns? It seems like you are trying to get column `'OWN_CAR_flag'` from the dataframe, but there is no such column.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I fixed the post so that it actually *asks a question*, and to [remove irrelevant chatter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721/kind-reminder-to-remove-noise) and the image link (code should be posted as text only, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). It's still not possible to help you from this code and error message, because we can't see your data, and because we don't know *what you intend for the code to do*.

Comment: That said, any proper Python tutorial should ensure that you understand basic errors, including `KeyError`. You should make sure you have an understanding of what error messages mean and how they work, before trying to follow a specific project tutorial or learning to use third-party libraries like Pandas. If you do understand, then please try to use that understanding to [look for a cause](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) first. For example, when the error happens, what is the value of `i`? In that situation, why should `df_cat_0[i]` work?

Comment: In the notebook you provided, the column `'OWN_CAR_flag'` is created in cell `[32]`. Make sure you created it before runing the loop

Comment: I have followed that notebook religiously that's what i am confused more of! Its showing that error when i try on my own. How can i share my own notebook here?